# Any benefit of writing only valid HTML in AngularJS applications?

Tags: angularjs

I notice some programmers strive to turn all angular tags into valid HTML. Things like writing directives in class or comments form instead of element form. And prefix all attributes with `data-`.

Is there any meaningful benefit in doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no practical benefit to doing this. Using element form works in all modern browsers and is far easier to read and maintain.

Even on older versions of IE, with a little extra work you can get custom elements to work. See https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/ie

Comment: upvote for the old IE note. Thank you Samuel Neff.